# How can i separate the text to another column in a database from a .txt file ? (the delimiter is a string)

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I got a .txt file like this:
"Rock also know as: Alternative rock"
I need to import that to a database using sqlite3 and python.
Each type in a different column like:

Rock       |             Alternative Rock

Thanks.

|: separate columns.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('chinook(1).db')
cur = conn.cursor()


file=open('subgenres3.txt','r') 
try: 
        file = open('subgenres3.txt', 'r') 
except: 
    print("file not found")  

f=file.read()
f=f.split("\n")   



for line in f:  
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO subgénero (subgenrename,subgenrealtname) VALUES (?,?)", (line,line)) 

conn.commit() 
conn.close()
```

Comment: `t = 'Rock ///////// Alternative Rock'` then you can just do `t.split('/////////')` to get a result of `['Rock ', ' Alternative Rock']`

Comment: @Tomahawk  Please clarify the format of the text file.  The other comment assumes that the slashes are present in the text, but I interpret the question to say the text looks like "Rock also know as: Alternative rock" and the slashes are just added by you to indicate different columns in the table.  Correct?  Whatever the case, please edit the question and **include an extended example of the text file with multiple lines of text**.  A single line is not a good example when asking for help parsing data.

Comment: FYI:  It's traditional to separate column values with a simple `|` (pipe symbol or vertical bar) and then format the data as code, like `Rock | Alternative Rock`.  Even better is to add a header line showing column names and horizontal line using dashes. `-----------|-------------` to separate the header line from the data, making a simple table.

Comment: FYI: Do not respond to other answers or add more detail by adding an answer. Either add a comment to the answer or edit the question to add more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep everything within python, then I suggest using [regular expressions (regex) within python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).  The following regular expression should be compatible with the latest python `re` module.  It has two capture groups that match the first and second fields.

```regex
^((?:\w|\s)+) also know as: ?((?:\w|\s)+?\w)\s*?$
```

A snippet that would get the two field values for each line would look something like

```py
p = re.compile('^((?:\w|\s)+?) also know as: *?((?:\w|\s)+?\w)\s*?$')

for line in f:
   m = p.match(line)
   subgenrename = m.group(1)
   subgenrealtname = m.group(2)
   ...
```

Comment: If you got an error using my suggested regular expression, then the text does not match and you need another regex.  First of all, you should add code to handle the case when there is no match.  (That is always good coding practice--don't just assume that everything will always execute smoothly, especially when importing external data.)  But I can't help you anymore since you did not edit the original question and add more details of the text file like I suggested... you did not clarify what the format of the text file was, and you did not add a more extensive example of the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient solution using sed and sqlite3.  It illustrates how to approach the problem and can easily be adapted to use as much python as you like:

```
sed 's/ *also known* as: */,/' subgenres3.txt > subgenres3.csv

cat <<EOF | sqlite3 'chinook(1).db'
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subgénero (subgenrename,subgenrealtname);
.mode csv
.import subgenres3.csv 'subgénero'
EOF
```